# ML.NET KMeans clustering - What is the Davies Boulding Index?

Tags: k-means, ml.net

I am using the `KMeans` clustering algorithm from ML.NET ([here](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning/blob/main/docs/samples/Microsoft.ML.Samples/Dynamic/Trainers/Clustering/KMeans.cs)) and when evaluating the model, I see `Davies Bouldin Index` in the model metrics.

What is the range of this index? What does its value of zero mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation the Davies Bouldin Index is:

"The average ratio of within-cluster distances to between-cluster distances. The tighter the cluster, and the further apart the clusters are, the lower this value is."
Also:

"Values closer to 0 are better. Clusters that are farther apart and less dispersed will result in a better score."
You can find more information on the Davies Bouldin Index in the following [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/machine-learning/resources/metrics#evaluation-metrics-for-clustering).